# Magento2 video thumbnail not getting displayed

Tags: magento2

Preview image of video not showing into frontend into product detail page in Magento2

[image]

Comment: That's got the magento placehilder behind it. Any errors? And have you checked the permissions on the pub media files & folders?

Comment: Yes, we have checked whole the permission and it it proper

Comment: Can you please re-upload the video and check?

Comment: @Arjun are you resolve this issue? I have also face the same issue on Magento 2.4.2 CE ? I have added a video on product programmatically show on the backend but not display on frontend